# Advanced Forum - how do I delete a forum?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using Advanced Forum - how can I remove the default forum created (General Discussion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure > Forums > You should see General Discussion listed, hit the Edit Forum link > Scroll down and hit the delete button

Comment: Well, that was easy enough. Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: I don't know, just wondering, why would you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: @NoSssweat because some things MUST be done programmatically, if you have multiple environments like local, dev, staging, production etc. with multiple developers working on the project and use version control systems for deploying between those environments.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a forum programmatically, you can use the following code (in an update script for example):

```
// First load the terms with the name "General discussion"
$terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name('General discussion', 'forums');
if (is_array($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
  // Since $terms is an array, we take the first (and ideally the only) item.
  $term = reset($terms);
  taxonomy_term_delete($term->tid);
}
```